# How do I resolve the unchecked cast problem IntelliJ is highlighting?

Tags: java, generics, cqrs

## Context

I’m building a command dispatcher for my CQRS application.

## Relevant Code

### Command Interface

```java
public interface Command {
  
}
```

### Command Executor Interface

```java
public interface CommandExecutor<T extends Command> {

  Mono<CommandResult> execute(T command);

}
```

### Command Dispatcher

```java
public class CommandDispatcher {

  private final Map<String, CommandExecutor<? extends Command>> executors = new HashMap<>();


  // Example usage
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    CommandDispatcher dispatcher = new CommandDispatcher();

    dispatcher.register(MakeRequestCommand.class.getName(), new MakeRequestCommandExecutor());

    dispatcher
        .dispatch(MakeRequestCommand.class.getSimpleName(), new MakeRequestCommand("Any iPhone"))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);

  }


  public <T extends Command> void register(String commandAlias, CommandExecutor<T> executor) {

    executors.put(commandAlias, executor);

  }


  public <T extends Command> Mono<CommandResult> dispatch(String commandAlias, T command) {

    if (!executors.containsKey(commandAlias)) {

      throw new RuntimeException("No executor registered for command %s".formatted(commandAlias));

    }

    CommandExecutor<T> executor = (CommandExecutor<T>) executors.get(commandAlias);

    return executor.execute(command);

  }

}
```

## The Problem

The following line is producing a warning in IntelliJ.

`CommandExecutor<T> executor = (CommandExecutor<T>) executors.get(commandAlias);`

> Unchecked cast: 'io.freesale.application.command.CommandExecutor<capture<? extends io.freesale.application.command.Command>>' to 'io.freesale.application.command.CommandExecutor'

Is this something I need to be concerned about / is there any way to resolve it (without suppressing warnings .)

I'm worried it is highlighting a flaw in my design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unchecked cast means literally that - Java cannot check whether the cast is valid or not (and this is due to type erasure), and so there will be no `ClassCastException`s at the point of the cast, which in general may make it harder to debug.

For example, if you did:

```
dispatcher.register(SomeTypeOfCommand.class.getName(), new SomeTypeOfCommandExecutor());

dispatcher
    // we're getting the SomeTypeOfCommandExecutor, but giving it AnotherTypeOfCommand
    .dispatch(SomeTypeOfCommand.class.getName(), new AnotherTypeOfCommand())
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

`SomeTypeOfCommandExecutor` is a `CommandExecutor<SomeTypeOfCommand>`. If the cast were *checked*, Java would see that casting `AnotherTypeOfCommand` to `CommandExecutor<SomeTypeOfCommand>` is an invalid cast, and throw an `ClassCastException` at the line:

```
CommandExecutor<T> executor = (CommandExecutor<T>) executors.get(commandAlias);
```

However, the cast is actually unchecked, so a `ClassCastException` is only thrown *later* down the line, when `SomeTypeOfCommandExecutor.execute` is called. At that point, Java can see that the passed in parameter is not a `SomeTypeOfCommand`. This may lead to confusing stack traces.

That is what the warning is warning you about. IMO, this isn't too much to worry about, since `executor.execute(command);` is not too far after the unchecked cast (it is *immediately* after), so you are basically "checking" the cast immediately on the next line anyway. If you want to be extra clear that you are checking the cast, you can add a method in `CommandExecutor` that looks like:

```
boolean canExecute(Object command);
```

And in implementations, you would just use `instanceof` to check `command`.

Side note: I would recommend that you use a `Class<?>` as the map's key type, if there can only be one command executor for each type of command. This way, in `register` and `dispatch`, you can require that class type and the command's type must be the same, which prevents things like this:

```
.dispatch(SomeTypeOfCommand.class, new AnotherTypeOfCommand())
```

You would do:

```
private final Map<Class<? extends Command>, CommandExecutor<? extends Command>> executors = new HashMap<>();

public <T extends Command> void register(Class<T> commandAlias, CommandExecutor<T> executor) {
    executors.put(commandAlias, executor);
}

public <T extends Command> Mono<CommandResult> dispatch(Class<T> commandAlias, T command) {
    CommandExecutor<T> executor = (CommandExecutor<T>) executors.get(commandAlias);
    if (executor == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No executor registered for command %s".formatted(commandAlias));
    }
    return executor.execute(command);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and great advice!